# SQL table with a single column and incremental id

Tags: sql, database-normalization

Simple DB design question, that I honestly can't quite put my finger on.

On many occasions, I have a type table, which consists of an ID and the type's name. Ala. a language code table would have 2 columns

TABLE: `language`

```
language_id (1,2,3)                 
language_code (et, en-us, de)
```

Now I would always hand out the language_id as a foreign key to other tables,

BUT

Which is better?

To hand out `language_id` as foreign key and then make joins to get the `language_code`.

OR

leave out the `language_id` altogether so that we have

TABLE: `language`

```
language_code (et, en-us, de)
```

and then we will just hand out the codes as foreign keys and no joins will ever be needed, when we want to know, for example, what is the user's mother tongue.

Opinions?

Comment: Since those language codes are pretty short (max. 5 chars - en_us), and *standardized* by ISO, those would seem to make good candidates to be used directly - I don't see much benefit in adding yet another `ID` here....

Comment: This is really just the "surrogate key vs natural key" debate. I'm not sure what the most recommended approach is; afaik it's contested on which is better. IMO since the codes are short and unlikely to change, I'd recommend the `language_code` only approach.

Comment: Normalization does not involve introducing new columns. In particular it does not involve introducing ids/surrogates. This is not a normalization issue. PS This is a faq. Please always google error messages & many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags & read many answers. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 9):

The answer is, it depends.

Under most circumstances, a reference table with a foreign key is desirable.  Here are a few reasons:

- You can include a foreign key reference that checks that the value is valid.
- You can readily add another value.
- You can include other information, such as the date added and a full name "English" rather than "en".

The performance hit is generally quite minor.  You would have a primary key index on the language id and it would be very fast.

Your language code is only two characters.  If you used a typical 4-byte key for the the reference, you would use up an additional two bytes in each record.  There are situations where including the language code directly would save space and effort.  However, for this to make a difference, you would be talking about an optimization on a very large database (say hundreds of millions of rows).

I would vote for a separate reference table and all the benefits that go with that.  Under some extreme cases, one might consider an alternative structure for particular reasons.

Comment: In addition to the answer above, having an ID as primary key will safeguard OP from situations where someone, for whatever reason, decides to change the 2-character code (ISO 639-1) of a language, or when your successors decide to use 3-character code (ISO 639-2) to represent language code.

Comment: Not necessarily, I could set up cascade rules, so that when some-one changes the language_code from say "et" to "est", then it cascade changes all the other tables also!

Comment: Language codes have some kind of hierarchy - I mean e.g. `es` and `es-pt`, `es-mx`. Sometimes you need to deal with the most narrow codes and sometimes you want to deal with only top-level part of the codes (es, en, ru and etc.). With reference table it'd be much easier!